# Blackberry Push SDK on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, tomcat, blackberry, java-me, push-notification

My client wants to do a blackberry application using Push SDK. he wants to host the application on Google App Engine. where the client sends the updates to the App Engine and app engine pushes the updates to the subscribed blackberry devices.

As i know blackberry Push API default comes with Tomcat Server. My problem is, **is it possible to implement Push API in Google App Engine? and how can i do it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Push API uses HTTP (and it [looks like it does](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/platform/pushapi.jsp#tab_tab_features)) then yes, you can certainly use it from App Engine - just implement their protocol as specified in [their docs](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/subcategories/?userType=21&category=BlackBerry+Push+Service+SDK).